# Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects and All User Shortcuts

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, installation

I have a VS 2013 Installer Project, it all works fine for the user that installs the app, however all other user profiles see the following when they run the shortcuts:

[image]

It appears that the shortcut is the issue here. If I go to program files and run the app directly and/or create a new shortcut the app runs with no issues.

I have set InstallAllUsers to True:

[image]

I also noticed if I set the InstallAllUsersVisable to True, it doesn't actually appear in the install wizard.

Shortcuts are added to the highlighted folders:
[image]

Is there a way to get around the install prompt? If not can I somehow get the installer to cache the msi so its accessible?

I did notice the shortcut path is just UC Extend, not the path to the exe:
[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. No amount for searching the net has helped me get past this. Really appreciate some help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a new installer project and the problem went away. I had applied VS 2013 SP1 since originally creating the project so maybe that was the fix.